# Secure javascript code from being executed by dev tools (Firebase)

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a big problem.

My database and authentication runs over Firebase.

I want to update a user to premium by calling this:

```
function getPremium() {
       firebase.database().ref('premium').child(user.uid).set({
        premium: true,
        })
```

Everything works great, user updated to premium.

Now a guy comes around who knows a little bit of javascript and Firebase
so he simply opened the dev tools and run this code:

```
firebase.database().ref('premium').set({
            iRuinedYourSite: true,
            })
```

What can I do about it?

Is it so unsecure or what am I doing wrong to prevent something like this?

Comment: We really need a canonical "Nothing on the client is secure" dupetarget.

Comment: Wrap all your code inside an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE): `(function() { // your code })();`, this way you can avoid exposing critical objects to the global scope, also try to obfuscate the production code. These are just tips to minimize the risk but as @T.J.Crowder said, nothing on the client is secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your **client-side** code can upgrade the user, then the user can upgrade themselves, full stop. There is nothing your code can do on the client that a sufficiently-motivated end user can't do from the client.

You need to have a server involved, gate-keeping the interaction.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Firebase's NodeJS Admin SDK to run a simple NodeJS Server that handles all of the premium requests. The NodeJS Admin SDK overrides Firebase Security Rules so you don't need to worry about that. Here's a link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Edit: You could also use Firebase Functions which is basically a NodeJS Server that uses a special package to interact with the database. Here a link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Is this also working? https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup in the part  "Run a Local Web Server for Development" this is exactly what you mean or?

Comment: No, you would only need to run a local web server for development if you are creating a website, and even then, it isn't necessary. What I would recommend is studying and learning the Firebase Functions commands and write a few commands for that. You can view a video made by the Firebase team here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvV9Vk9iOCQ, and the docs page is in my answer above. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, I setup an function which displays a string out of the database, but how I call this function in the normal website?

Comment: In the website, you would set a value in a certain section of the database for each premium request. Then in the functions, you would create a trigger that watches for this variable to be set. Once it realizes that the variable has been set, it can set the user's status to premium. Now another way to do this if you want to integrate with an actual payment gateway is to have the payment gateway talk to the cloud function through some sort of api. Then when the payment gateway approves the payment, then it can tell your cloud function to upgrade the user.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants to accept PayPal payments with Firebase,

Connect your Firebase project with Zapier, then connect Zapier with your Paypal account and let Zapier handle everything. It will cost you 25$ / Month but will bring in the security you need.